# operator overloading about Abstract class (cpp)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overloading, abstract

In student.h file

```
class Student {
 protected:
  string Name;
  int Stu_num;
 public:
  virtual void print() = 0;
  // constructor...
}

class Grad_Student: public Student {
 private:
  string Lab;
 public:
  void print();
 // constructor...
}

class Undergrad_Student: public Student {
 private:
  string Major;
 public:
  void print();
  // constructor...
}
```

in student.cpp file

```
bool operator == (const Student& x, const Student& y) {
 if (typeid(x) != typeid(y)) return false;
 else // dosomething..
}
```

I want to compare child of Student class; Grad and Undergrad.
in main.cpp when i comapre two student class, it doesn't work..

```
Grad_Student grad1 = Grad_Student("Max", 11, "Hubo");
Student *std1 = &grad1;

Grad_Student grad2 = Grad_Student("Max", 11, "Hubo");
Student *std2 = &grad2;

cout << (std1 == std2) << endl; // it always prints 0.
cout << (*std1 == *std2) << endl; 
// I think this line should work, but makes error.
// error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Student' and 'Student')
```

Should i overload operator== in student class?
give me a hint...

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_ please describe the problem you are asking about.  Otherwise, we must guess what isn't working.

Comment: Shouldn't `Undergrad_Student` derive from `Student`?

Comment: Well as you posted... Currently your overridden operator returns nothing at all. you might want it to do something... Like compare the numbers and names of student objects amd return true of they're the same or false of they're not the same.

Comment: @gun bos: your code seems to have multiple serious errors, any one of which could explain the problem.  Please read WBuck's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69248204/421195).  Please "upvote" and "accept" the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: cout << (*std1 == *std2) << endl;  this line makes error below.
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('Student' and 'Student')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your overloaded equality operator does nothing... You need to compare something in the body and return a `boolean` result.

Also, your `Undergrad_Student` currently doesn't derive from `Student`..
Furthermore, since you're comparing 2 `Student` objects you can just make the equality operator overload a member function taking 1 argument.

Something like this:

```
class Student {
public:
    explicit Student( int id )
        : id_{ id }
    { }

    bool operator==( const Student& other ) const {
        return id_ == other.id_;
    }

    virtual void print() const = 0;
    virtual ~Student( ) = default;

protected:
    int id_;
}; 

class Grad: public Student {
public:
    explicit Grad( int id )
        : Student{ id }
    { }

    void print() const override {}
};

class Undergrad : public Student {
public:
    explicit Undergrad( int id )
        : Student{ id }
    { }

    void print() const override {}
};

int main( ) {
    Grad s1{ 11 };
    Undergrad s2{ 12 };

    // Prints false.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( s2 == s1 ) << '\n';

    Grad s3{ 42 };
    Undergrad s4{ 42 };

    // Prints true.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( s3 == s4 ) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thank you for anwer
my question had some problems, i modify the question
my problem is 'Undergrad' and 'Grad' have different member which is lab and major, and it makes hard to compare..